# Can you set event.data with jquery trigger

Tags: jquery

With jQuery `.on()` you can pass an optional parameter to set the event data. Can you do this with trigger as well?

Answer (score 79):

## Short Answer:

Can **trigger()** pass data to your event handlers? **Yes** (as additional parameters)

Can **trigger()** pass data into the event.data object directly? **No** (only **on()** does this)

```
// Using this will pass myData to every event handler as the second parameter. 
trigger('myEvent', [myData]) 
// Instead of this
on('myEvent', function(evt) {...});
// You would do this
on('myEvent', function(evt, myData) {...});
```

## Long Answer

**The trigger() method** does 5 main things.

1. It creates a JQueryEventObject with the type and optional namespace you give it
2. It sends or emits an event of a specific type that travels up the DOM until it reaches the top or its propagation is stopped.
3. It defines the signature of event handlers for that type of event.

   - function(event) {...} is the default
4. It passes the event as the first parameter to those handlers
5. It (optionally) passes additional parameters to any handlers of the event

   - function(event, additionalParams) {}

Numbers 3 and 5 are most important and relevant to you. Since you implicitly define the api for handling this event, you want to be consistent with how you trigger events so that people who use your code can be consistent with how they use it.

**Example 1** Consistency

```
function Car(speed, tires, brakes) {
    this.speed = speed;
    this.tires = tires;
    this.brakes = brakes;
}

Car.prototype.brake = function(amount) {
    // You can do this (Event handler will have access to these parameters)
    car.trigger('brake.car', [this.speed, this.brakes, this.tires, amount])
    // Or this (Event handler will have access to these parameters)
    car.trigger('brake.car', [this, amount])
    // but try not to mix and match with the same event type
}
...
//This is the first way from above (choose one or the other, but don't mix and match).
passenger.on('brake.car', {person: passenger}, function(evt, carSpeed, carBrakes, carTires, brakeAmount){
    if(brakeAmount > 50)
        passenger.hangOnTight();
    }
})

...
// This is the second way from above (choose one or the other, but don't mix and match).
passenger.on('brake.car', function(evt, car, brakeAmount){
    if(brakeAmount > 50)
        passenger.hangOnTight();
    }
})
```

**Example 2** Here is the typical example showing both trigger() and on():

```
jQuery(document).on('eventName' {eventData1: 'foo', eventData2: 'bar'}, function (evt, extraParam1, extraParam2) {
    //This code runs when the event is triggered
    console.log(evt.data.eventData1) // foo
    console.log(evt.data.eventData2) // bar
    console.log(extraParam1) // 'extra param 1'
    console.log(extraParam2) // 'extra param 2'
});

jQuery(document).trigger('eventName', ['extra param 1', 'extra param 2']);
```

So just remember.

- .trigger(): emit the event and define parameter 2, 3, etc consistently if needed
- .on(): event is bubbling up the dom. do some stuff, add to or use event data and use the extra params that trigger added or not.
- Tangent: If you want to define event handlers for dynamic elements that can be added or removed arbitrarily, this is very easy with jQuery. See this answer: [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: Good answer but I am unable to use this while my DOM element is dynamically (ajax call) added.. Too bad

Comment: @Delphine I've updated my answer to cover this. See the end of my answer for a relevant link.

Answer (score 29):

I hope I didn't get you wrong but do you mean passing additional data with the `trigger` method?

```
$(app.Model).trigger("foo", additionalData);
```

And somewhere else...

```
$(app.Model).on("foo", callback);

var callback = function(event, additionalData) {
   console.log(additionalData);
}
```

Note that if you pass additional data with `trigger`, your first parameter in the callback function always is the actual event you are triggering.

The `app.Model` I used in the parenthesis is the object that should trigger an event and that also listens on that event. Think of it as kind of a namespace. You can always use `document`, any DOM selector or even object you like, just make sure that both the `trigger` and the `on` must use the *same* object (that is, DOM elements that are removed from the DOM temporarily are error-prone).

Comment: +1 for you, the docs don't really mention how to access this additional data.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this way:-

**Example**

```
  //Create a new jQuery.Event object without the "new" operator.
  var e = jQuery.Event("click");

  // trigger an artificial click event
  jQuery("body").trigger( e );
```

You can pass event.data too with the same approach. Refer this **[Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)**

Comment: Can you show with code example how to pass event.data with this approach?

Comment: var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.data = "a nice data";
jQuery("body").trigger( e );

Comment: That is the **correct** answer for this question. Other "answers" are hacks.

Comment: This doesn't work though. `e.data` is undefined by the time it gets to the `on` handlers.

Answer (score 16):

This was the approach I took.

```
$('#foo').on('click', { init: false }, function(e, data) {
        data = data || e.data;
        console.log(data.init); // will be true in the trigger, and false in the click.
    })
    .trigger('click', { init: true });
```

Answer (score 4):

I know an workaround we can use for this

```
$("button").on("click", function(event) {
   event.data = $(this).data('events'); // get the data value 
   alert(event.data); //use your data as you want
});


//Now set the data value and trigger
$("button").data('events','youreventsvalue').trigger("click");
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/qvtQS/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The documentation says:

> .trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )
>
> Note the difference between the extra parameters we're passing here and the `eventData` parameter to the `.bind()` method. Both are mechanisms for passing information to an event handler, but the `extraParameters` argument to `.trigger()` allows information to be determined at the time the event is triggered, while the `eventData` argument to `.bind()` requires the information to be already computed at the time the handler is bound.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery site you can see the declaration for the `trigger` function: `.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )`

The `extraParameters` must be an array or a single object and you will be allowed to get these objects with arguments[1+] (arguments[0] is equal to event object).

So, here's an example:

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event) {
  if ( arguments.length > 1 ) {
    $.each(arguments, function(i,arg){
      alert("element " + i + " is " + arg);
    })
  }
});

$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event', { 'test' : 'attr from object' }, 123]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the same `dataObject` that you defined with the original :

```
$('selector').on('eventName', dataObject , functionName)
```

will be also sent when you use `$('selector').trigger('eventName').

you can also pass parameters (like other mentions in their answers) but those parameters will be additional arguments (you will still have the `dataObject` you set in the `.on()` function).

Comment: Good point. It's worth mentioning that dataObject is accessible by data property of event. Something like this function foo(e) { console.log(e.data)}

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand the philosophy behind this.  An event involves two entities: listener and dispatcher.  The `event.data` field was intended to be used by the listener only.  It's sort of like assigning a name to a phone number:

```
$("(818)548-2733").on("incomingcall", null, "Mom", pickup);
```

You could pick up the phone and wait for the other side to tell you that she is your Mom.  Or you can use `event.data` to attach the extra information relevant to this event.

The `$.trigger` and `$.triggerHandler` methods are called by the dispatcher side of an event.  That's why they don't let you specify the `event.data`.  Instead, you can use their `extraParameters` argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("pressedButton").on("click", function(event) {
   var buttonID = $(this).data('buttonID');
   alert(buttonID); // alerts 'save' string passed as an argument
});

$("pressedButton").data('buttonID','save').trigger("click");
```

Comment: This is valid solution. Use it, it is the simples way ;-)

Comment: ...and a super dangerous way. What if the pressed button already has data on it? This does nothing to preserve the previous data items.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
  <input id="btn" type="button" />
    <input id="btn2" type="button" />​
    $("#btn").bind("click",function(e) {
        var data2 = {type:"click",name:"Raptors",sport:"basketball"};
        $("#btn2").trigger(data2);
    });
    $("#btn2").bind("click",function(e) {
       console.log(e.name + " " + e.sport);
    });
```