# How can I put parametres into JQuery.Event data property and trigger it?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-trigger

The goal is to pass parametres through event.data, here is complete example where I tested it : [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/Virgili/xgf1uhd1/)

```
$el.trigger( $.Event('click.NGB', { example: '1' }));
$el.trigger( $.Event('click.NGB', {data: { example: '2' } })); // :-(
$el.trigger( $.Event('click.NGB', [{ example: '3' }]));
$el.trigger( $.Event('click.NGB', [{ data: { example: '4' } }])); 
$el.trigger( $.Event('click.NGB'), { example: '5' });
$el.trigger({ type: 'click.NGB', data: [{ example: '6' }] }); // :-(
```

I don't know why if an Event object has a data property we can't access it...

But with '.on' function it's works! :-(

```
$('#response').on( 'click.NGB', {example: '7'}, function(e){ e.data.example; } );
```

Anyone know how to do? :-)

**ANSWER**

After all documentation and tests, I've decided use this method :

```
$el.trigger('click.NGB', [ {example : '8'} ] );
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401538/passing-parameters-on-jquery-trigger

Comment: It looks like the data is put in the `Event` object when you create it, but it gets lost by the time it gets to the handler.

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) says: _The following properties are also copied to the event object, though some of their values may be undefined depending on the event:_ and `data` is in that list.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! but.. why in function '.on' is posible but not in '.trigger'?

Comment: Apparently `data` always contains whatever you give as the extra data argument to `.on()`. If you don't give that argument, it's treated as giving `undefined`. That overwrites whatever you specified when creating the `Event` object.

Comment: @RST I already looked! look the example 6. is the last comment of linnium from first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584892/can-you-set-event-data-with-jquery-trigger) question.

The "Short Answer" on that question should answer your question quite nicely.

> Can trigger() pass data to your event handlers? Yes (as additional parameters)
>
> Can trigger() pass data into the event.data object directly? No (only on() does this)

Comment: Thanks!! sometimes stack is infinite

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to send extra data along with the event, you do that with additional parameters, both where you send and receive the event:

Receiving:

```
// Note discrete param --------------v
$("#foo").on("whatever", function(e, param) {
  display("param: " + JSON.stringify(param));
});
```

Sending:

```
// Note discrete param -------v
$("#foo").trigger("whatever", 42);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/gehok/1/)

Comment: My goal is use the property data of the Event!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed here - http://jsfiddle.net/xgf1uhd1/7/

```
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $el = $('#response');

    $el.trigger( $.Event('click.NGB', { example: '1' }));
});

$('#response').on('click.NGB', function () {
    $ev = arguments[0];
    example = arguments[1];
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find('pre').append('value is === ' + arguments[0].example);
});
```

Comment: this is my example! ;-)

Comment: yes, and this is what you wanted right? your code did not work

Comment: my code works... look '1 -> undefined', value of example is 1 but data is undefined!