# How fill event.data with jQuery event object?

Tags: jquery, events

Im still getting undefined.

Pls see example

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){

    console.log(e);
});


// Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
var e = jQuery.Event( "click", { pageX: 64, data: {'foo': true}, data123: {'foo': true} } );

// trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 64
$( "body" ).trigger( e );
```

Other event properties (eg pageX i can set, but data never).

Comment: [Here is the solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/aNDgC/204/) [Taken from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20707308/2569323)

Comment: Thx, but this is not what i want. I want fill event.data via jQuery.event.
All properties are working (event.pageX, event.pageY etc), but event.data are always undefined, i dont know why.

Comment: [Because it is `reserved`.](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

Comment: Oh, thx, where is some explanation that is really reserved?